# How to debug stack-overwriting errors with Valgrind?

Tags: stack-overflow, valgrind

I just spent some time chasing down a bug that boiled down to the following.  Code was erroneously overwriting the stack, and I think it wrote over the return address of the function call. Following the return, the program would crash and stack would be corrupted. Running the program in valgrind would return an error such as:

```
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xEA 0x3 0x0 0x0
==9222== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4e925a8.
```

I figure this is because the return jumped to a random location, containing stuff that were not valid x86 opcodes.  (Though I am somehow suspicious that this address 0x4e925a8 happened to be in an executable page.  I imagine valgrind would throw a different error if this wasn't the case.)

I am certain that the problem was of the stack-overwriting type, and I've since fixed it. Now I am trying to think how I could catch errors like this more effectively.  Obviously, valgrind can't warn me if I rewrite *data* on the stack, but maybe it can catch when someone writes over a return address on the stack.  In principle, it can detect when something like 'push EIP' happens (so it can flag where the return addresses are on the stack).

I was wondering if anyone knows if Valgrind, or anything else can do that? If not, can you comment on other suggestions regarding debugging errors of this type efficiently.

Comment: I'd recommend you to file a wishlist bug against valgrind.

Comment: The return address is not pushed with `push` instruction, but implicitly by the `call` instruction. Which makes it easier to detect where it is.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, that would be a neat feature in Valgrind, wouldn't it?  Yes, you're correct that `call` pushes the return address, I wrote it this way just to be completely clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the problem happens deterministically enough that you can point out particular function that has it's stack smashed (in one repeatable test case), you could, in gdb:

1. Break at entry to that function
2. Find where the return address is stored (it's relative to `%ebp` (on x86) (which keeps the value of `%esp` at the function entry), I am not sure whether there is any offset).
3. Add watchpoint to that address. You have to issue the `watch` command with calculated number, not an expression, because with an expression gdb would try to re-evaluate it after each instruction instead of setting up a trap and that would be extremely slow.
4. Let the function run to completion.

I have not yet worked with the python support available in gdb7, but it should allow automating this.

Answer (score 7):

In general, Valgrind detection of overflows in stack and global variables is weak to non-existant. Arguably, Valgrind is the wrong tool for that job.

If you are on one of supported platforms, building with `-fmudflap` and linking with `-lmudflap` will give you much better results for these kinds of errors. Additional docs [here](http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/mudflap).

**Udpdate:**

Much has changed in the 6 years since this answer. On Linux, *the* tool to find stack (and heap) overflows is [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), supported by recent versions of GCC and Clang.

Comment: Seems that the http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/mudflap  is a dead link. Perhaps this link can be used instead: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging

Comment: @bgoodr I've updated the answer: mudflap is much weaker and carries much greater memory overhead, compared to current state of the art.

Comment: Thanks for that tip about the memory overhead!

Comment: Awesome recommendation this of AddressSanitizer! Made my life super easy just now tracking down a nasty bug :)

Comment: ASAN is wonderful. It's unfortunately not usable for me because of the memory overhead. :(