# Multibale connection in Contiki-ng Stack error

Tags: c, contiki, contiki-ng

I'm trying to implement my version of clustering in Contiki-ng. I took some inspiration from this code: [Clustring example](https://github.com/andavid0/PANTHER-network-simulation/tree/master/one-cluster-topology)

What I did basically was that I created two connection:

```
static struct simple_udp_connection broad_conn;  
static struct simple_udp_connection uni_conn;
```

However, though the code compiles and starts running in cooja, it stops showing me an error in the stack. I traced the error message and it looked like it came from this part of the code in stack-check.c:

```
  if(p >= (uint8_t*)GET_STACK_ORIGIN()) {
    /* This means the stack is screwed. */
    return -1;
  }
 actual = stack_check_get_usage();
allowed = stack_check_get_reserved_size();
if(actual < 0 || allowed < 0) {
LOG_ERR("Check in inconsistent state: %" PRId32 " vs. %" PRId32 "\n", actual, allowed);
```

There is no memory overflow, and besides the callback functions, there is nothing in the code. The only thing that I think off is that it's because of the connections, but I just don't see why.
This is the code of nodes.c:

```
    #include "contiki.h"              
    #include "simple-udp.h"          
    #include "sys/log.h"              
    #define LOG_MODULE "SensorNode"   
    #define LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_INFO 
    #define UDP_PORT_BROADCAST 1234   
    #define UDP_PORT_UNICAST 4321     
    static struct simple_udp_connection broadcast_conn;  
    static struct simple_udp_connection unicast_conn;    
    static uip_ipaddr_t CH_address; 

PROCESS(nodes_process, "Nodes");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&nodes_process);
/*---------------------------------Not Me------------------------------------------*/
static void
broadcast_receiver(struct simple_udp_connection *c,
        const uip_ipaddr_t *sender_addr,
        uint16_t sender_port,
        const uip_ipaddr_t *receiver_addr,
        uint16_t receiver_port,
        const uint8_t *data,
        uint16_t datalen)
{
    LOG_INFO("Received broadcast '%.*s' from ", datalen, (char *) data);
    LOG_INFO_6ADDR(sender_addr);
    LOG_INFO_("\n");
    uip_ipaddr_copy(&CH_address, sender_addr); 
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
unicast_receiver(struct simple_udp_connection *c,
        const uip_ipaddr_t *sender_addr,
        uint16_t sender_port,
        const uip_ipaddr_t *receiver_addr,
        uint16_t receiver_port,
        const uint8_t *data,
        uint16_t datalen)
{
    LOG_INFO("Received reply '%.*s' from ", datalen, (char *) data);
    LOG_INFO_6ADDR(sender_addr);
    LOG_INFO_("\n");
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(nodes_process, ev, data)
{

    static struct etimer periodic_timer; 
    static unsigned count;
    static char str[32];

    PROCESS_BEGIN();
     /* Not me also */
    /* Initialize UDP broadcast connection */
    simple_udp_register(&broadcast_conn, UDP_PORT_BROADCAST, NULL,
                        UDP_PORT_BROADCAST, broadcast_receiver);

    /* Initialize UDP unicast connection */
    simple_udp_register(&unicast_conn, UDP_PORT_UNICAST, NULL,
                        UDP_PORT_UNICAST, unicast_receiver);

    /* Send messages to the clusterhead every 60 seconds */
    etimer_set(&periodic_timer, 60*CLOCK_SECOND);

    while(1) {
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&periodic_timer));


        LOG_INFO("Sending message %u to ", count);
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(&CH_address);
        LOG_INFO_("\n");

        snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "hello %d", count);
        simple_udp_sendto(&unicast_conn, str, strlen(str), &CH_address);
        count++;
        etimer_reset(&periodic_timer);

    }

    PROCESS_END();
}
```

Any help in explaining this would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug stack-overwriting errors with Valgrind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813444/how-to-debug-stack-overwriting-errors-with-valgrind)

Comment: Without having access to your code, it's going to be hard to tell. I first thought you could [use Valgrind to detect where the stack gets corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814426/518853), but it seems [AdressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is the way to go, especially for a small piece of code.